# In rancher's private Catalogs Template files are not shown

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher

In case of Rancher the Private Catalogs get added and the private catalogs are also displayed but the `helm charts` associated to a private catalog can't be accessed. If I select a catalog I don't find the templates files listed.

In case if we put the same `helm chart` on a public catalog the templates file get listed. The issue so clearly is with Rancher and not with the `helm charts`.
I tried to put the helm charts on different private repository like ACR and git private repo and the issue still persists so also the issue with the registry is ruled out.

Steps to reproduce:

1) Create a Private App Catalog (any, but I used ACR)
2) Add the app catalog to Rancher by providing the correct Credentials.
3) Go and Launch the app
4) The helm chart(pushed in prev steps) gets listed.
5) Try to go and Launch the App.

Result:

You find that there is no template files listed (Values.yml,Deployment.yml etc are not listed )
Logs of Rancher Server

> [ERROR] Failed to load chart: Error fetching helm URLs: [Error in HTTP
>   GET of [_blobs/**.tgz], error: Get //user:***@_blobs/**-0.1.0.tgz:
>   unsupported protocol scheme ""]

I get a unsupported Protocol schema error when the chart tries to read the index.yml and then ries to get the *.tar.gz file

The issue seems to be linked to other issues like : https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/15671

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use Rancher Charts for charts to be correctly listed in the app catalog of Rancher.
Rancher Chart and Helm chart have some differences which are listed here : https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/catalog/custom/creating/

**There are two ways to use charts in Rancher:**

- Helm chart way that requires the GIT server responding to GET request ( charts are stored as tar.gz file along with index.yml file).
- Rancher chart way where the charts are stored as normal files ( store the whole helm chart folder as it is , no need to gunzip it as in helm chart way) on GIT server.

In my case i had the tar.gz file that had the helm chart and index.yml file that renders the chart. This way is supported by Rancher only if there is some external server responding to the GET request which finds the chart from the index.yaml. Github pages support this feature that is why I was able to use the helm chart in Rancher.

Solution : I unzipped the tar and directly uploaded folder on GIT and use this GIT repo in Rancher to get the chart correctly listed under app catalog.

*Do remember to use .git at the end of the url defined in the app catalog.*